# Database error when creating entities using hook_update_N

Tags: 7, entities, database, updating

I'm trying to create an entity (using `entity->save()`) in a hook_update_N function. The errors appear at the mysql insert query in the entity's insert function; the insert strings are wrapped in `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

I get a series of warnings:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established mod_person.entity.inc:402

mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO) mod_person.entity.inc:403
```

Followed by the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'val' at row 1
```

When I remove the `mysql_real_escape_string()` from the mysql insert query code it works! However now I'm worried that leaves the server vulnerable.

My questions are:

[1] Why does using `mysql_real_escape_string()` work in normal site operation and not through hook_update_N?

[2] Do I need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` with Drupal 7 database queries or is there another way?

I suppose I could remove the `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the update and then put them back but that feels like I'm missing the point somewhere.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Drupal 7 uses PDO, so none of the mysql_* functions should be used. The entity class needs to use db_insert, db_update, etc

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Clive said, you will want to use the [Database API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) (db_update, db_insert) or use an [Entity Metadata wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers).

Comment: thanks - so I was using direct concatenation in the `db_query()` using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Are you suggesting that I should be using the array of variables argument in `db_query()` to substitute variables into the query - and does that ensures security?